# C# return a list of all required properties in a class

Tags: c#, reflection, extension-methods

I'm trying to get a dictionary containing the Property and the DisplayName of all properties in a class that have the Required Attribute.

I'm trying to work off of this extension method that I have but PropertyDescriptor does not contain a definition for Required. Any direction would be appreciated

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> GetDisplayNameList<T>()
    {
        var info = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T))
            .Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.DisplayName);
        return info;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you just need to check that the property has the `Required` attribute defined on it. You can access this via `.Attributes`. For example:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetDisplayNameList<T>()
{
    var info = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T))
        .Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
        .Where(p => p.Attributes.Cast<Attribute>().Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(RequiredAttribute)))
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.DisplayName);
    return info;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Personally I find [`.Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<RequiredAttribute>() != null)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194292(v=vs.110).aspx) a lot cleaner.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I usually do use that, however this is on `PropertyDescriptor` rather than `PropertyInfo`, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetNameToDisplayNameDictionary(List<T>() list) =>
   typeof(T)
      .GetProperties()
      .Where(p => p.GetAttribute<RequiredAttribute>() != null)
      .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetAttribute<DisplayName>().Name);
```

I'm guessing a little here about the `DisplayName` as I'm away from my computer...