# C# 11 - detect required property by reflection

Tags: c#, c#-11.0

C# 11 added support for required properties.

```cs
public class Example
{
    public required string Value { get; set; }
}
```

How do I detect that the property is declared as required by reflection?

Please note this is a different question from [Return a list of all required properties in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990832/c-sharp-return-a-list-of-all-required-properties-in-a-class) because that question is from 2017 about a custom attribute, this is about `required` property keyword which is new in C# 11 (2022).

```cs
PropertyInfo prop = typeof(Example).GetProperty("Value");
//bool isRequired = prop ...?
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If we [run your code through sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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), we see that your code becomes:

```cs
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(1)]
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Nullable(0)]
[RequiredMember]
public class Example
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private string <Value>k__BackingField;

    [RequiredMember]
    public string Value
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <Value>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        set
        {
            <Value>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }

    [Obsolete("Constructors of types with required members are not supported in this version of your compiler.", true)]
    [CompilerFeatureRequired("RequiredMembers")]
    public Example()
    {
    }
}
```

So... just test for the existence of the `RequiredMemberAttribute` on the property via `Attribute.IsDefined(propertyInfo, typeof(RequiredMemberAttribute))`. I guess you should also test for `RequiredMemberAttribute` on the type too.

Comment: So that's who crashed `sharplab` so I couldn't test `required` ...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I prefer "extreme validation" to "crashed"